# Generalized additive models - formula for basis functions

Tags: generalized-additive-model, splines, smoothing

I'm trying to understand the basics of GAMs. 
Wood's book "Generalized Additive Models: an introduction with R" introduces GAMs via a cubic spline basis $b_j(x)$ (see p. 122), where 
$b_1(x)=1, b_2(x)=x$ and $b_{i+2}(x)=R(x, x_i^*)$ ($1 \leq i \leq q-2$, $x_i^*$ are knot locations),  where
$
  R(x,z)=\left[ (z-1/2)^2 -1/12 \right]\left[ (x-1/2)^2 -1/12 \right]/4 - 
\left[(|x-z|-1/2)^4 - 1/2 (|x-z|-1/2)^2  +7/240 \right]/24.
$

But there's definitely an error in the last expression since it's a spline of order 4.  How should the correct formula look like?

Could anyone suggest another simple but mathematically rigorous (and relatively comprehensive) introduction to GAMs?

Comment: This formula is on page 126 of the 1st edition of the book by Simon Wood. The book refers to the mathematically rigorous explanation of Gu (2002), page 37 (https://doi.org/10.1007/978-1-4757-3683-0). But it is not simple.

Answer (score 1):

GAM in "Introduction to statistical learning" (page 283) is defined as extension to multiple regression. Lets begin with a term representing simple multiple regression: 
$ \hat{y} = \beta_{0} + \beta_{1}x_{1} + ... +\beta_{n}x_{n} +\epsilon_i$. Now instead of just multiplying each variable $x_{1},x_{2},...,x_{n} $ with coefficients $ \beta_{1}, \beta_{2},...,\beta_{n} $, you could use some functions $ f_{1},...,f_{n} $
 to model the relationship between predictors and response variable:
$ \hat{y} = f_{1}(x_{1}) + ... + f_{n}(x_{n}) +\epsilon_i$. By doing this, you are adding possibility to model each predictor's contribution to the response variable with non-linear functions. This is the idea of GAMs.

Comment: I think the OP knows that but the question is whether the formula quoted is correct for a spline of that order.

Comment: OP clearly stated that he/she is trying to understand the basics, and asked for another explanation using math expressions. Sorry if the response is not suitable.